# Running NSRunLoop causes main thread to hang

Tags: cocoa, freeze, nsrunloop

In a Cocoa application, running code like this:

```
NSDate* date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:30.0];
while (date.timeIntervalSinceNow > 0) {
    [NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:date];
}
```

on the main thread appears to cause the main thread to hang for 30 seconds. I find this surprising because I would have thought the code would basically act as a message pump and allow for user interface events to actually be processed.
What explanations can people provide for why this causes the main thread to hang?

Answer (score 1):

The main Cocoa application event loop is built on top of a run loop, but it's not **just** a run loop input source.

If you want a message pump, you should use the `-nextEventMatchingMask:...` and `-sendEvent:` methods of `NSApplication` or `NSWindow`.

But, what are you really trying to achieve? Why are you trying to run the event loop for 30 seconds? Can you achieve what you want with a timer or `dispatch_after()`?

Comment: There was need to actually cause a program to hang for a period of time, and someone had accomplished this using the run loop. I was puzzled as to how they were able to accomplish this because I thought the run loop would actually prevent the application from hanging.